# Counting distinct values output from a grouped SQL Count function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a database that holds information about volunteers and their participation in a range of events.

The following query gives me a list of their names and total attendances

```
SELECT 
     volunteers.last_name, 
     volunteers.first_name, 
     count (bookings.id)
FROM 
     volunteers, 
     bookings
WHERE 
     volunteers.id = bookings.volunteer_id
GROUP BY 
     volunteers.last_name, 
     volunteers.first_name
```

I want the result table to show the distinct number of attendances and how many there are of each; So if five people did one event it'd display 1 in the first column and 5 in the second and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your table structure  and how your result should look like

Comment: Including sample table data.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  You should also learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Further, you mention "event" in your description of what you want, but you have no such column or table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want what I call a "histogram of histograms" query:

```
select numvolunteers, count(*) as numevents, min(eventid), max(eventid)
from (select b.eventid, count(*) as numvolunteers
      from bookings b
      group by b.eventid
     ) b
group by numvolunteers
order by numvolunteers;
```

The first column is the number of volunteers booked for an "event".  The second is the number of events where this occurs.  The last two columns are just examples of events that have the given number of volunteers.

Comment: Thanks Gordon your solution was just what I was after.